# Remove existing formatting of csv cell copied into text editor in django

Tags: python, django, csv, nicedit

I have made a forums website in Django. The textarea for entering question has [NicEdit](http://nicedit.com/) integrated for formatting purpose. However if I copy a cell from a CSV file and paste it into the textarea and save it, the database has some extra tags added along with it.
Example:
On copying a cell which contains this info:

> Audio in this file is not clear. Not only in this file but also in
>   some files. Please check it.

and pasting it in textarea and saving, the way it is getting saved in the database is

> \r\n\t\r\n\t\r\n\t\r\n\t\tbody,div,table,thead,tbody,tfoot,tr,th,td,p {
>   font-family:"Liberation Sans"; font-size:x-small
>   }\r\n\t\ta.comment-indicator:hover + comment { background:#ffd;
>   position:absolute; display:block; border:1px solid black;
>   padding:0.5em; } \r\n\t\ta.comment-indicator { background:red;
>   display:inline-block; border:1px solid black; width:0.5em;
>   height:0.5em; } \r\n\t\tcomment { display:none; }
>   \r\n\t\r\n\t\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\r\nAudio
>   in this file is not clear. Not only in this file but also in some
>   files. Please check it.

As a result, I'm unable to get the proper results for further use of this data. Is there any way I can remove this excessive formatting in python? As I'm working in django and fetching data from views.py I need to do this in python and I'm unable to do it till now. Currently I have a regex filter to remove html tags but it'd be better if I'm able to remove this complete formatting(html+css) in one go.

Comment: Don't know how NicEdit plays into this, but can you show the code of your django form that contains the field which contains the html and css clutter upon sending the form? Also the template where you render this form.

Comment: @ascripter The django form is of category forms.Form and textarea is a charField(widget=forms.TextArea()) type. It's a big project so not desirable to show the complete template over here, but the logic is just rendering all the form fields in it. And this added javascript for the text box:
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
 new nicEditor({
        iconsPath: "{% static 'website/js/nicEditorIcons.gif' %}",
        buttonList : ['fontSize','bold','italic','underline','strikeThrough','subscript','superscript','html','image', 'link', 'forecolor', 'bgcolor']
    }).panelInstance('id_body');
});

Comment: Been looking into NicEdit. I'd say the string that is sent is your intended text including the formatting information that NicEdit adds. If you include a Richt Text Editor, you get Rich Text. Why don't you just save it this way in the DB?

Comment: Actually I don't have the authority to change the text editor. Is there any way to do it without having to change the editor?